# Ubuntu Apache2 XSLT

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I'm trying to install libxslt on Ubuntu for Apache2, and I cannot find a way to do so. There is no package for it, so how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Built from the `libxslt` source package is `libxslt1.1`

```
sudo aptitude install libxslt1.1
```

Alternative, you can download a .deb from http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/libxslt1.1

You might also want the development package, `libxslt1-dev`

```
sudo aptitude install libxslt1-dev
```

or http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/libxslt1-dev

Comment: It installed fine, now how do I enable it for Apache/PHP use? My phpinfo() output does not include it.

Comment: You need the php5-xsl package: `sudo aptitude install php5-xsl`